# Python: block character will not print

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii, block, non-ascii-characters

In IDLE, `print(chr(219))` (219's the block character) outputs "Û".

Is there any way to get it to output the block character instead?

This might actually be some sort of computer-wide problem, as I cannot seem to get the block character to print from anywhere, copying it out of charmap and into **any** textbox just results in the Û.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the correct character set.

```
3>> print(bytes((219,)).decode('cp437'))
█
3>> ord(bytes((219,)).decode('cp437'))
9608
3>> hex(9608)
'0x2588'
3>> print('\u2588')
█
```

[Unicode Character 'FULL BLOCK' (U+2588)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your python shell is probably using either ISO-8859-1 or Unicode, not he same character set as Character Map.

chr(219) is also U+00DB, which is probably the Unicode character Û.  I don't know what character set you are using, but there aren't any symbol characters that early in the Unicode character set.